# Docker npm run test very slow

Tags: reactjs, docker

Learning Docker and playing around with Node apps and I'm seeing some consistently poor behavior, especially when it comes to hot reload (works but takes over 20 seconds the first time) and testing.

Docker File to create the initial Image

```
FROM node:alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY ./package.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY ./ ./

CMD ["npm","run","start"]
```

Docker Compose file

```
version: '3.9'
services:
  frontend:
    image: frontend:v1
    working_dir: /app
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
```

App Configuration (defaults, no changes to any of the files):

```
npx create-react-app
```

Testing results from within the container:

```
 PASS  src/App.test.js (6.284 s)
  ✓ renders learn react link (93 ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        10.926 s, estimated 18 s
Ran all test suites.

Watch Usage: Press w to show more.
```

App.test

```
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import App from './App';

test('renders learn react link', () => {
  render(<App />);
  const linkElement = screen.getByText(/learn react/i);
  expect(linkElement).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

On my local host everything works within expected time frames but when moving over to a docker container things seem to slow down.  I'm curious to know where to look in regards to resources allocated to the docker container?

FYI whether I run docker compose or docker run directly the test results and the 20 second hot reload time still persist.  I've looked for some settings to fix this but can't seem to find any.  Thanks in advance.

Also thought that I would add that there is nothing in the logs except for standard React output such as Starting the Dev Server and you can now view your app in the browser with the appropriate links.  Webpack compiled successfully.  With the tests it's the same thing, no errors, standard output just really long test run times within the container which tells me memory or CPU issue but I didn't know where to look for that.  Thanks

Comment: What OS are you on? If Linux, what's your Docker storage driver? It's recommended to use `overlay2`; if your Docker install is configured with a compatibility driver like vfs or even aufs file IO may be noticeably slow.

Comment: Mac OS...I'm using Docker Desktop (running everything via cli).  Using defaults, 4 CPU's 8 GB RAM and 1GB Swap.  Adding overlay2 to damon.json didn't do anything to help...same results

Comment: Bind mounts are known to be slow on MacOS and some configurations of Windows.  I'd recommend using a non-Docker Node setup for day-to-day development, which avoids a wide range of problems; you should just be able to `brew install node` to get it (assuming you're using Homebrew as a package manager).

Answer (score 0):

This is a [known issue](https://github.com/jestjs/jest/issues/1395) with jest in docker containers on mac. Especially in watch mode.

There are lots of github issues and SO questions about it. The general consensus seems to be that Jest and docker just don't play nice together. Jest is very aggressive in spinning up threads and hitting the file system many times. Resource-constrained or virtualised environments like Docker impose an overhead on thread coordination and file system access.

Most of the time you don't notice the overhead, but because of how Jest works, you really see the impact. Jest has been written, tested, and optimised for macbook pros: very fast, multi-core, SSD machines. It works great on those devices. Put it into a docker container or onto a free CI platform like Travis, and it does not cope. I've seen similar problems when you run jest on really locked-down corporate devices with overzealous virus scanners that freak out over Jest's repeated file system access.

Your best bet is to play around with flags like `--runInBand` or `--maxWorkers=4`, and try to find a setting that performs well. Or just give up on docker for frontend development, as I have :)